# Workspace being overwritten by Team Foundation Server 2005

Tags: mapping, workspace, tfs-2005

Due to a workspace path length limitation, I had to shorten the workspace path mappings used by one of my team builds. To my surprise, each time I launch my build, it's being somehow overwritten by with the previous path mappings.

I deleted the Team Foundation cache (C:\Documents and Settings\TFS_BuildService\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation\1.0\Cache) and launch the build to again see that my workspace had been overridden.

With no other solution, I desparately modified the workspace mappings directly in the Team Foundation Server database. But again, after launching my build my workspace path mappings were replaced by the old ones.

Anyone has any idea about this strange TFS behaviour I am encountering ?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to edit build definition in Visual Studio by right clicking on build in team explorer and selecting "Edit build"?

I remember that we faced similar problem and solution was to change folders there.

Comment: Changing the build folder in the "Build Directory on selected machine" dialog box while launching my build solved my problem. 

Unfortunately, I still don't know why I was facing my problem but anyway, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I think, that problem lays in fact, that TFS overrides (and overwrites) workspace directory with one in build configuration.

Comment: Do you know where does TFS store this information ? I have not been able to find this information in TFS's databases.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I hadn't enough time to investigate it further.